# How to optimize a utility function that contains step function?

Tags: optimization

I have an optimization problem with an uncommon utility: to find a $\beta$ that maximizes

$$
r^{T}\cdot H(X\cdot\beta)
$$

where $H()$ is a Heaviside step function as in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

$r$ is a vector of size 1000

$X$ is a 1000x50 "tall" matrix

$\beta$ is a vector of size 50

I am familiar with gradient descent, which is how I usually solve an optimization problem. But Heaviside function does not work with gradient descent. So I am wondering if anyone here could shed some light on how to solve such optimization problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows, assuming $r_i \ge 0$ for all $i$.  Let $M_i$ be a (small) upper bound on $-(X \cdot \beta)_i$.
Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether $(X \cdot \beta)_i \ge 0$.  The problem is to maximize $$\sum_{i=1}^{1000} r_i y_i$$ subject to
$$-(X \cdot \beta)_i \le M_i(1 - y_i)$$
for all $i$.
This "big-M" constraint enforces $y_i=1 \implies (X \cdot \beta)_i \ge 0$.

Comment: HI Rob, thanks for answering this. but if y_{i} = 0, then X*beta>= - 1  * M_{i}; which at least overlaps with the case of y_{i} = 1 , right?

Comment: Yes, $y_i=0$ forces only a redundant constraint. As long as the “reward” $r_i\ge 0$, this big-M constraint is sufficient.